# Python while loops issues

Tags: python, loops, variables

I'm wanting this code to constantly keep spitting out the variables {actual, wb, pbactual, pbsim}, which is what I have right now but I want wb and pbsim to be different values eachtime, because right now they are just printing the same list everytime, I would like it to be random. BTW the other variables are set by me and if you need them let me know!

## Python

```
while win == False:
    while run:
        x = random.randint(1, rwb)
        if x not in wb:
            wb.append(x)
            pbactual.sort()

        if len(wb) == nwb2:
            while npb2 > 0:
                x = random.randint(1, rpb)
                if x not in pbsim:
                    pbsim.append(x)
                    npb2 = npb2 - 1
            run = False
            
    print(actual, wb, pbactual, pbsim)
```

## Variables

```
nwb = 5
nwb2 = 5
rwb = 10
npb = 2
npb2 = 2
rpb = 20
ballswin = 0
pbwin = 0
actual = []
wb = []
win = False
run = True
```

Comment: We need the other variables

Comment: I am not getting same list.
>>> random.randint(1,142)
Output: 66
>>> random.randint(1,152)
Output: 10

Comment: @SanderBakker i have added the variables

Answer (score 0):

Something like following should get you working:

```
import time
random.seed(time.time())
```

Setup random with time seed, every time different.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was aiming for, as all I want for "pbsim" and "wb" to be random and different every time the loop runs through. But currently it is random but when it runs through again the values in the list are the same as the previous output. E.G. I want 1,3,4 and the next output 3,6,8 and the next be more random numbers, but rn its 1,2,3 then 1,2,3 again and again. If that makes any sense?